# non-combat role-playing skills in ICE Rolemaster

Tags: skills, rolemaster, non-combat

My group plays ICE exclusively and has for the past 15 years or so.

Recently, a friend of the DM's joined with no RPG experience.  A problem has arisen regarding the role playing skills such as "Diplomacy" and "Leadership" and others.   My view is that these skills are used for the DM to determine how an NPC only will react to player characters in a given circumstance, when the DM has knowledge that the NPC does not, and has no effect on PCs because they are controlled by us, the players.

For instance, I may want to take charge of a group of NPC soldiers in a crisis situation and i would use my leadership skill to get them to follow orders and get them organized or whatever.  The diplomacy skill would be used to get an NPC to react favorably to you, even though he or she may not have any knowledge of you or your history or motivations.

The new player has always complained that because he has high leadership and tactics skills (he plays a Paladin) that the rest of the group should heed his ideas when figuring out a plan of action, then follow that plan, even though I as a player disagree with it.  In other words, I should be forced to follow his lead and have my character do things that I would otherwise not do, to the detriment of said character.  This is only one example, but you get the jist.  He has convinced the other players of this, as well as the DM.   What are your thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: What is the specific problem you want advice on/are asking about? Is it how non-combat skills are supposed to work, whether those skills should be able to convince your character, how to talk to your GM/group about this, or something else I'm not spotting? "What are your thoughts?" is often a bit to broad for us and opens it up to too many answers which aren't really relevant for you and/or not supported/supportable.

Comment: It may be useful to expand the question a little: What do the rules say should happen? That seems like a seismic shift if the system's been used differently for 15 years—what did the player say that was so convincing? Is the new player an actual, for-reals tactical genius and a born leader?

Comment: Is this in mass combat where Leadership and Tactics skills mechanically come into play?  Do you get bonuses from his skills in mass combat?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I can't see a question (as currently presented) that fits within the guidelines of this stack. "What are your thoughts?" is a forum question - we need a question that can be answered like "Which interpretation do the rules support?" or "Can the control of my character be taken from me in this way?"